# How to snap the screen to a View's edge inside scrollview?

Tags: android, android-view, android-scrollview

I got some content inside a scrollview, its like boxes, a lot of boxes.
There are input fields in each of them.

I want to snap the screen to the edge of a box, when the input field is touched.
I know there is a function with scrollView it is scrollTo(x,y); or something like this.

Can i use this to snap the screen ? And if yes, how can i get a view's edge's coordinates, or something that i need?

Anyone can help ?

(Sorry for bad english i hope you understand my problem)